# ClickHouse Aggregates - GROUP BY DAY/MONTH/YEAR(timestamp)?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate, aggregate-functions, clickhouse

Is there a way in ClickHouse to do a GROUP BY DAY/MONTH/YEAR() with a timestamp value? Having hard time figuring it out while rewriting MySQL queries to ClickHouse. My MySQL queries looks like so...

```
SELECT COUNT(this), COUNT(that) FROM table WHERE something = x AND stamp BETWEEN startdate AND enddate

SELECT COUNT(this), COUNT(that) FROM table WHERE something = x AND stamp BETWEEN startdate AND enddate GROUP BY DAY(stamp)

SELECT COUNT(this), COUNT(that) FROM table WHERE something = x AND stamp BETWEEN startdate AND enddate GROUP BY MONTH(stamp)

SELECT COUNT(this), COUNT(that) FROM table WHERE something = x AND stamp BETWEEN startdate AND enddate GROUP BY YEAR(stamp)
```

Quite simple AND SLOW in MySQL, but I do not know how to do the aggregates in ClickHouse.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know which count belongs to which day, month, year, etc

Comment: That's the thing. MySQL knows and has DAY(), MONTH() and YEAR() functions to respectfully turn timestamp to each day, month or year in the GROUP BY clause. ClickHouse does not. Wondering how to rewrite it for ClickHouse. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To get part of date use function [toYear](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/#toyear), [toMonth](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/#tomonth), [toDayOfMonth](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/#todayofmonth) by the next way:

```sql
SELECT
    toMonth(time) AS month,
    count()
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        number,
        addDays(now(), number) AS time
    FROM numbers(8)
)
GROUP BY month

/*
┌─month─┬─count()─┐
│     1 │       7 │
│     2 │       1 │
└───────┴─────────┘
*/
```

---

To get multiple grouping set use [WITH ROLLUP](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/group-by/#with-rollup-modifier)-modifier:

```sql
SELECT
    toYear(time) AS year,
    toMonth(time) AS month,
    toDayOfMonth(time) AS day,
    count()
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        number,
        addDays(now(), number) AS time
    FROM numbers(8)
)
GROUP BY
    year,
    month,
    day
    WITH ROLLUP

/*
┌─year─┬─month─┬─day─┬─count()─┐
│ 2021 │     2 │   1 │       1 │ // day
│ 2021 │     1 │  29 │       1 │ // day
│ 2021 │     1 │  31 │       1 │ // day
│ 2021 │     1 │  26 │       1 │ // day
│ 2021 │     1 │  25 │       1 │ // day
│ 2021 │     1 │  28 │       1 │ // day
│ 2021 │     1 │  30 │       1 │ // day
│ 2021 │     1 │  27 │       1 │ // day
│ 2021 │     1 │   0 │       7 │ // month
│ 2021 │     2 │   0 │       1 │ // month
│ 2021 │     0 │   0 │       8 │ // year
│    0 │     0 │   0 │       8 │
└──────┴───────┴─────┴─────────┘
*/
```

Comment: This should do, I guess. Thanks! Accepting answer!

Comment: Does not include rows where count is 0, though.

Comment: COALESCE(COUNT(this), 0) now helping for GROUP BY to return rows with 0 count() or sum(). Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: consider using [ORDER BY WITH FILL](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/order-by/#orderby-with-fill).